# Can I use wifi and LAN on win server 2012?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2

Iam not a network guy. But recently installed Windows server r2 and configured active directory, DC and file server. Currently domain users are using file server over wifi.

Server IP configured in wifi is 192.168.10.100

All domain users are transferring files via wifi on win server. Now I want if user is connected with LAN then user can also access same file server on LAN connectivity.

Is it possible? If possible then how DNS will be configured in lan? For instance wifi server IP is 192.168.10.100 which I have added in wifi LAN. and i have added this IP in users PC in TCP/IP in DNS. And setting up getting IP automatically from the dhcp router.

If iam not wrong we can not assign same server IP in wifi and Ethernet . can some one plz give me hint so that I can Google?

Comment: Why would you use both on the server? The wired and wireless clients should all be configured on the same Layer 3 network. It isn't necessary for the server to be connected wirelessly.

Comment: Actually we are using only wifi connectivity but in other building there is no wifi, but lan is present there. So I want to connect same configured 2012 server to be connected on that lan?

Comment: Wireless and Wired connectivity is a Layer 2 function. IP connectivity is a Layer 3 function. If all the devices are on the same IP (Layer 3 ) network then it doesn't matter if they're connected to the wired network or the wireless network.

Comment: Let me explain my scenario: 8 Users are in Building A, connecting Server 2012 via Wifi. But in Building B there are two users and there is no Wifi but Lan is available there. So can Lan users also access same server? If yes then Server IP of Wifi is 192.168.10.100 and gateway/dns 192.168.10.1 so what will be the Lan Ip?

Comment: Draw a network diagram including the physical connections and the ip address settings and post that in your question.

Comment: Thank you  joeqwerty: Sure I will. Deeply appreciated your assistance.

Answer (score 1):

Deactivate the WIFI and use the LAN connection. WIFI is by default disabled on a Windows Server, not for nothing as it's the best way to get network speed issue.

For your question, you can't have the same IP on the network.

Comment: Currently we are using Wifi on server but in other building there is only LAN and there are only two users in that building. So thought if lan can work there and wifi users will be connected in Building A on same server where two Lan users can connect same server in Building B

Comment: @Naeem You mix two thing, your wifi must be able to talk to your lanand vice versa.